# Example where probability theory fails without $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I have just started reading theory of probability in a measured theory based approach and was wondering if someone could give an example where probability fails without using $\sigma$-algebra (or let's say simply using power set of $\Omega$). I know measure theory, but was just curious about some interesting example in probability.

Comment: What do you mean by "without using $\sigma$-algebra"?  If you don't use that, what will you use instead?

Comment: perhaps the question is along the lines of 'why did I go through all that measure theory to do probability theory? Are there any new tricks I can pull off now, or is it simply a good foundation so that I sleep well at night?'

Comment: In fact, the question is what Calvin explained. Why using measure theory? Why not defining probability measure on all the subsets of $\Omega$?

Comment: Because you can cover $[0,1]$ with countable non-measurable sets and you can argue that each of these sets should have "measure" zero  and yet their union has measure one... http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9781118032732.app2/pdf

Comment: That is, you can use all sets only if you assume measures are finitely additive but not countable...

Comment: Thanks Sergio. I think I got my answer by your comments, especially the second one. Would you mind putting them as an answer?

Comment: 1. The power set of $\Omega$ is  a $\sigma$-algebra. 
2. There are countable additive measures (and probabilities) defined in the power set of $\Omega$.  For instance, let $a \in \Omega$, define, for any $B$ in the  power set of $\Omega$,  $\delta_a(B)=1$ if $a\in B$ and $\delta_a(B)=0$ if $a\notin B$.  It is easy to see that $\delta_a$ is a countable additive measure and $\delta_a(\Omega)=1$.

Comment: The reason we need σ-algebras for probabilities is that, in 
the general case, we don't want to restrict the concept of 
probability measure to just those cases that can be defined 
in the power set of $\Omega$.